# Faking a tuple class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, types

I need to have a new type, say `MyTuple`, so that I can create objects like this: `obj = MyTuple((1,2,3))`, such as:

1. `obj` behaves exactly as a native tuple (also in performance)
2. `isinstance(obj, tuple)` returns `False`.

The reason behind this is that I need to use tuples as indexes in Pandas, but when Pandas detects that the values of the index are tuples, it uses multiindexes instead, which I don't want.

Thus, the following does not work:

```
class MyTuple(tuple):
    pass
```

This fulfills my first requirement but not the second one, so if I use `MyTuple` objects as indexes, Pandas still creates multiindexes from them.

Another solution is to use composition instead of inheritance, implementing the `Sequence` abc and having the true tuple as an object attribute, providing wrapper methods around it:

```
from collections.abc import Sequence
class MyTuple(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, initlist=None):
        self.data = ()   # A true tuple is stored in the object
        if initlist is not None:
            if type(initlist) == type(self.data): self.data = initlist
            elif isinstance(initlist, MyTuple): self.data = initlist.data
            else:  self.data = tuple(initlist)
    def __getitem__(self, i): return self.data[i]
    def __len__(self): return len(self.data)
    def __hash__(self): return hash(self.data)
    def __repr__(self): return repr(self.data)
    def __eq__(self, other): return self.data == other
    def __iter__(self): yield from self.data.__iter__()
```

This type fulfills the second requirement (`isinstance(obj, tuple)` returns `False`), and provides the same interface than a true `tuple` (you can access the elements via indexes, you can compare it with another tuples, you can use it as dictionary keys, etc). Syntactically and semantically this solution is good for me.

However it is not a true `tuple` in terms of performance. In my application I have to perform tons of comparisons betweens these objects (and of these objects with true `tuple`s), so the method `MyTuple.__eq__()` is called tons of times. This introduces a performance penalty. Using `MyTuple` instead of true tuples, my program multiplies by six the runtime.

Then, what I need is something like my first attempt (a class which inherits from `tuple`), but which later can "lie" about being a tuple, if asked via `isinstance()` (because this is how Pandas finds out if it is a tuple and thus should create a multiindex).

I read about Python's [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html) and `__instancecheck__()` methods, but I think that they are not useful here, because I should implement those methods in `tuple`, instead of `MyTuple`, but this is not possible.

Perhaps some tricks with metaclasses would do it, but I do not fully understand the concept to see its relationship with this problem.

Can I achieve my goals somehow?

Comment: "obj behaves exactly as a native tuple (also in performance)" - if you want native code performance, you're going to have to write native code.

Comment: @user2357112 Well, the first implementation (a class which inherits from tuple) does not incur in the overhead of the second implementation, and is good enough for my first purpose. But it fails at the second, which is why I'm asking

Comment: How does Pandas handle an index of `((1,2,3),)`?

Comment: I've tried to inherit `MyTuple` from `tuple` and then modify `tuple`'s `__instancecheck__` to not recognize instances of `MyTuple`, but Python does not allow to modify builtin types. :{ What about creating a class that a) accepts an iterable as construction argument, b) stores all the values of that iterable inside an encapsulated `tuple`, c) defines all the special methods a `tuple` has and in those methods'  bodies but performs a tail-call to the inner tuple with the same arguments? Should not impose a huge performance penalty.

Comment: @bipll What does mean "tail-call" in this context? How it is different your proposed solution for the second "solution" I gave in the question? Could you provide an example of code in an answer?

Comment: @JoshLee Looks like a good idea, but It doesn't work either when building pandas Series from dictionaries, which is my case. For example: `d={((1,2),): 100}; pd.Series(d)` creates a series with index `(1,2)` and value `NaN` instead of `100`. Apparently When pandas sees a tuple of lenght=1 as index, it decides to go without the tuple and uses only it first element (which is good), but then uses that index as key in the dictionary, and that fails because `d[(1,2)]` does not exist (`d[((1,2),)]` does), hence the `NaN`.

Comment: Have you tried setting [`tupleize_cols = False`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html#pandas.Index)?

Comment: Have you tried using your index tuple's on df.values (numpy.ndarray)?

Comment: @TemporalWolf I didn't know about that option. However, it is used to create indexes, not Series or DataFrames from lists and dictionaries, which is my problem. However you gave me some new ideas and hope. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyTuple(object):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.data = tuple(iterable)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return tuple.__getitem__(self.data, i)

t = MyTuple((1, 2, 3))
print(t[1])
print(isinstance(t, tuple))
```

Other methods analogously.

Still not a true `tuple` performancewise, but the closest I can think of... probably.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem you'll hit with performance is that Python's underlying collateral is implemented in highly-optimized C (or other language -- there are a dozen or so good implementations, and more coming).

When you implement something in Python, remember that it's interpreted, or partially-compiled at best.  You cannot get optimum performance when each line has to be reinterpreted at run time, even given good intermediate code.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of that, but, as said, `MyTuple(tuple): pass` is good enough for me because the overhead with respect to a true tuple is minimal. Now I only need to find out how to hide the fact that `MyTuple` is a `tuple`, to fool Pandas. (btw, I did not downvote your answer)

Comment: Okay, then ... can you map all of your class methods, *except* __type__ identification, to the native **tuple** methods?

Comment: Do you mean from python or from C? If from python I think that this is precisely the contrary of what I meant. I dont want to wrap all native tuple methods into my own (because this will increase overhead). I want to inherit from tuple all methods except the type identification, if this is possible. If you mean to do that in C, that is beyond the scope of my abilities and it is undesirable nevertheless for my case. I need pure python only.

Comment: I meant it in Python: not *calling* the tuple method, but a direct reference.

Comment: If you refer to something like: `class MyTuple(tuple):pass` and later assign methods like this: `MyTuple.__eq__ = tuple.__eq__`, `MyTuple.__len__=tuple.len`, and so on, that does not work either, because if you try  for example `len(MyTuple())` you get the exception: `TypeError: descriptor '__len__' for 'tuple' objects doesn't apply to 'MyTuple' object`. Too bad...

Comment: Oh.  Maledictions.